# How to solve Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 18, Problem 36.b)

Tags: calculus

> For all  integrable $f>0$ we have
> $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} \log f \leq \log \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f \right)$$
> Prove that
> $$\left|L(\log f, P_{n})- \int_{a}^{b} \log f\right|< \epsilon $$
> $$\left|L(f, P_{n})- \int_{a}^{b} f\right|< \epsilon $$

For $\log$ continuity,
$$ \left| \log\left(\frac{1}{b-a}L(f, P_{n})\right)-  \log\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}  f\right)\right|<\epsilon$$

I also know that
$$\frac{1}{b-a}L(\log f, P_{n}) \leq \log\left(\frac{1}{b-a}L(f, P_{n})\right) $$

With all this, how could I conclude that $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} \log f \leq \log \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f \right)\quad?$$

Comment: What is $L(\cdot,\cdot)$?

Comment: This is very confusing. Is the very first statement not what you need to prove in this problem? What are your two "Prove that" statements following? Make clear what you know from part a) and from earlier results in the book. Spivak directs you to use a result from the appendix of Chapter 13. Have you used that?

Comment: I suspect concavity might play a role here?

Comment: @copper I believe that was used (in part a)) to establish what OP said "I also know" ...

Comment: You have to assume $f$ is convex in $[a,b]$ and $P_n$ is a partition.

Comment: @xpaul The result is true for any integrable $f$, it does not need to be convex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this theorem (It is from Spivak):

Theorem 1. Suppose that $f$ is integrable on [a, b]. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that, if $P = \{t_{0}, ..., t_{n}\}$ is any partition of [a, b] with all the lengths $t_{i} - t_{i-1} < \delta$, it follows that:
$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) - \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \right| < \epsilon,$$
for any Riemann sum formed by choosing $x_{i}$ from $[t_{i-1}, t_{i}]$.

In your case $P_{n}$ is a particular partition and $x_{i}=arg\ min_{s\in[t_{i-1},t_{i}]}f(s)$

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what you are trying to show. If you are just trying to conclude the last statement, then there is a straightforward way using a property of concave functions. This is basically [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_form)

If $c$ is a differentiable concave function (such as $\log$), then for any $t,\bar{t}$ in the domain, we have $$c(t) \le c(\bar{t}) + c'(\bar{t}) (t-\bar{t}).$$

In particular, $\log t \le \log \bar{t} + {\dfrac1{\bar{t}}} (t-\bar{t})$. Now replace $t$ by $f(x)$, integrate over $[a,b]$ and divide by $b-a$ to get
$${1 \over b-a} \int_a^b \log f(x) dx \le \log \bar{t} + {1 \over \bar{t}} {1 \over b-a} \int_a^b (f(x) - \bar{t}) dx.$$

Now set $\bar{t} = \int_a^b f(x) dx$ to get the desired result.

No partitions were harmed in the making of this answer.